# Understanding RPS on Locust summary result

Tags: performance-testing, load-testing, locust

I want to understand the meaning of RPS on locust. I don't get what exactly the meaning of RPS is, and how to understand it on load testing.

I try to load testing some HTTP request, when I start with client:100 and hatch rate:10, say on 50 user I got like 60 RPS, and at 100 I got 90 RPS and after I continue the load test for around 30 second I got my RPS on 270

Please kindly tell me what exactly is RPS, and why it increases significantly after reach maximum client.